# Page refreshes and only shows Ajax data instead of the original page content when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a webpage that allows the user to enter the hour, minute, and second for a Pomodoro timer. Upon clicking the start button, the timer should start counting down.

When I click the button, the page refreshes to a blank page that has nothing except for the Ajax data `{"hours":1,"minutes":2,"seconds":3,"totalTime":3723}` on the top left corner of the page. All the page content, including the form and CSS, disappears. The URL is the same /pomodoro.html before and after submitting the form. When I check network, I get all 200 status for GET and POST.

Here's my app.py:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/pomodoro.html", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def pomodoro():

    if request.method == "POST":

        hours = request.form.get("hours")
        minutes = request.form.get("minutes")
        seconds = request.form.get("seconds")

        # Check if the input is blank.
        if not hours or not minutes or not seconds:
            return apology("A positive integer must be entered.", 400)
        
        hours = int(hours)
        minutes = int(minutes)
        seconds = int(seconds)

        # Check if user input is valid aka no negative numbers
        if hours < 0 or minutes < 0 or seconds < 0:
            return apology("There is no negative time...", 400)
        
        # Calculate the total number of seconds from the user inputs
        total time = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds

        return jsonify({'hours' : hours, 'minutes' : minutes, 'seconds' : seconds, 'totalTime' : totalTime})
        

    else:
        return render_template("pomodoro.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

pomodoro.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Pomodoro
{% and block %}

{% block script %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">

    // This function will be executed after the HTML is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        // Calculate timer
        function timer(totalTime) {
            totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
            totalSeconds = totalTime % 60;

            totalHours = 0
            if(totalMinutes > 60) {
                totalHours = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
                totalMinutes = totalTime % 60;
            }
            totalTime -= 1
            alert(totalTime + "and" + totalHours)
            return [totalSeconds, totalMinutes, totalHours, totalTime]
        }
        

        // Hello1 works
        setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById("cancel_button").innerHTML = "Hello1";
            loadNewDecimal()
        }, 1000)


        function loadNewDecimal(){
            // Hello2 works
            document.getElementById("start_button").innerHTML = "Hello2";

            document.getElementById("start_button").onclick = function(e) {
            
                // Hello3 works
                document.getElementById("cancel_button").innerHTML = "Hello3";
                
                var time = JSON.stringify({
                    seconds : $('#seconds').val(),
                    minutes : $('#minutes').val(),
                    hours : $('#hours').val(),
                    totaltime : totalTime,
                });

                $.ajax({
                    data : time,
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/pomodoro.html',
                    dataType : 'JSON',

                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        console.log('Works');

                        // Countdown timer
                        while(totalTime > -1) {
                            var time = timer(totaltime);
                            alert(time[0])

                            $('#hours').val(data.hours);
                            $('#minutes').val(data.minutes);
                            $('#seconds').val(data.seconds);

                        }
                    }
                });

                e.preventDefault();
            };
        };
    });

</script>
{% and block %}

{% block the main %}
    <form action='/pomodoro.html' method="POST">
        <div id="countdown_container">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" placeholder="Hours" min="0"></li>
                <li><input type="number" id="minutes" name="minutes" placeholder="Minutes" min="0" max="59"></li>
                <li><input type="number" id="seconds" name="seconds" placeholder="Seconds" min="0" max="59"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="buttons_container">
            <button id="start_button" class="btn btn-secondary">Start</button>
            <button id="cancel_button" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I've tried changing the innerHTML at various stages and narrow down the problem to Ajax call. Neither the console or alert in Ajax call executes. The only things in the console are DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension, which according to other posts, don't affect my code. How do I return the countdown time in the Ajax data in the same input field instead?

Thank you.

UPDATE: This code worked for me if anyone wants to use it for reference.

```
{% block script %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    // If on click event is here, print out the dictionary

    // This function will be executed after the HTML is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Calculate timer
        function timer(totalTime) {
            let totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
            let totalSeconds = totalTime % 60;

            let totalHours = 0
            if(totalMinutes > 60) {
                totalHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
                totalMinutes = totalTime % 60;
            }
            return [totalSeconds, totalMinutes, totalHours]
        }
        
        setInterval(function(){
            loadNewDecimal()
        }, 1000)


        function loadNewDecimal(){
            document.getElementById("start_button").onclick = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                $.ajax({
                    data : {
                    seconds : $('#seconds').val(),
                    minutes : $('#minutes').val(),
                    hours : $('#hours').val(),
                    },
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/pomodoro.html',
                    dataType : 'JSON',

                    success: function(data) {
                        let totalTime = data.hours * 3600 + data.minutes * 60 + data.seconds;

                        while(totalTime > -1) {
                            var time = timer(totalTime);
                            totalTime -= 1

                            $('#hours').val(time[2]);
                            $('#minutes').val(time[1]);
                            $('#seconds').val(time[0]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        };
    });

</script>
{% end block %}

{% block the main %}

    <form action='/pomodoro.html' method="POST">
        <div id="countdown_container">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" placeholder="Hours" min="0"></li>
                <li><input type="number" id="minutes" name="minutes" placeholder="Minutes" min="0" max="59"></li>
                <li><input type="number" id="seconds" name="seconds" placeholder="Seconds" min="0" max="59"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="buttons_container">
            <button id="start_button" type="submit" name="start_button" class="btn btn-secondary">Start</button>
            <button id="cancel_button" type="submit" name="cancel_button" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>

{% end block %}
```

Answer (score 0):

the form is submitted on the **#start_button** click.
On a form submit the current page is redirect to the url specified by the attribute "action" of the form and use the method specified in the "method" attribute.

if you want to prevent the page redirect you need to prevent the submit of the form by using an event listener

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I still got the same page with the Ajax data.